# How to create new type element to form API?

Tags: 7, forms

[Drupal form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) provides some built in type of element to build a form. But I want to create other type such as:

```
$form['mail']['#type'] = 'email';
```

And the output I want it to be:

```
<input class="input-1" type="email" id="edit-mail" name="mail" maxlength="128">
```

So, how can i do that?

Comment: [`hook_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [`hook_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7). See the 
[`form_example_elements.inc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_elements.inc/7) file from the [Example: Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/group/form_example/7) module, and the [Creating Custom Elements](https://drupal.org/node/169815) documentation guide.

Note that the [Elements](https://drupal.org/project/elements) module already provides a form element type for HTML5 mail inputs.